# I am facing issue in do while in c language "undefined input"

Tags: c, loops, undefined, do-while

I was trying to run do while loop for following function I want to make a loop which can run continue if user puts any wrong alphabet\number I have created entire code but I am facing a very small issue which is written as "undefined input" but I have declared the "input" word in my code
Can you please  tell me what is the problem and can you fix it will be very helpful for a beginner programmer like me and please tell me the answer in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float square(float side);
float circle(float radius);
float rectangle(float length, float breadth);

int main()
{

  do
  {

    char input;

    printf("Choose 's' for square\n");
    printf("Choose 'c' for circle\n");
    printf("Choose 'r' for rectangle\n");

    scanf("%c", &input);

    if (input == 's')
    {
      float side;
      printf("You have choosen sqaure \n");
      printf("Enter the value of length \n");
      scanf("%f", &side);

      printf("%f", square(side));
      printf("Thank You For using my program :) \n");
    }
    else if (input == 'r')
    {
      float a, b;
      printf("You have choosen rectangle \n");
      printf("Enter the value of length \n");
      scanf("%f", &a);
      printf("Enter the value of breadth \n");
      scanf("%f", &b);

      printf("%f", rectangle(a, b));
      printf("Thank You For using my program :) \n");
    }

    else if (input == 'c')
    {
      float rad;
      printf("You have choosen circle \n");
      printf("Enter the value of radius : \n");
      scanf("%f", &rad);

      printf("%f", circle(rad));
      printf("Thank You For using my program :) \n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Enter The Correct letter ! \n");
    }
  } while (input != 's' || 'c' || 'r');
  return 0;
}
float square(float side)
{
  return side * side;
}

float circle(float radius)
{
  return 3.14 * radius * radius;
}

float rectangle(float lenght, float breadth)
{
  return lenght * breadth;
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about a compilation error then please copy the exact and complete error message into your question.

Answer (score 2):

`input` is defined inside `do {}`, but you are using it outside that. Move the line `char input;` before `do`.

Additionally, your loop condition is incorrect. Use this:

```
while (input != 's' && input != 'c' && input != 'r');
```

Comment: I would maybe suggest making the loop into either a `do {} while (0)` with an explicit `continue` in the invalid case, or a `do {} while(1)` with explicit breaks in the valid cases. (though hoisting `input` out of the loop and checking it explicitly is also an option)

Comment: @0xRyN  Can you please explain me what will "continue" statement does in this code it will help me to understand this code better.

Comment: @NikhilGaikwad continue makes the while loop restart. Just think of it as a way to start the loop again without executing all the remaining code.

Answer (score 0):

Define `input` outside of your `do-while` loop.

The while loop condition is incorrect as @VLL said.

I have rewritten your code to be better and more readable.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

float square(float side);
float circle(float radius);
float rectangle(float length, float breadth);

int main() {
    char input;  // Keep input outside of the while
    while (1) {  // Loop forever until bad input
        printf("Choose 's' for square\n");
        printf("Choose 'c' for circle\n");
        printf("Choose 'r' for rectangle\n");
        scanf(" %c", &input);
        if (input == 's') {
            float side;
            printf("You have choosen sqaure \n");
            printf("Enter the value of length \n");
            scanf("%f", &side);
            printf("%f\n", square(side));
        } else if (input == 'r') {
            float a, b;
            printf("You have choosen rectangle \n");
            printf("Enter the value of length \n");
            scanf("%f", &a);
            printf("Enter the value of breadth \n");
            scanf("%f", &b);

            printf("%f\n", rectangle(a, b));
        } else if (input == 'c') {
            float rad;
            printf("You have choosen circle \n");
            printf("Enter the value of radius : \n");
            scanf("%f", &rad);

            printf("%f\n", circle(rad));
        } else {
            printf("Invalid input \n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Thank you for using my program :)\n");
        break;  // If we don't go inside the "else", we exit the while loop
    }
    return 0;
}
float square(float side) { return side * side; }

float circle(float radius) { return 3.14 * radius * radius; }

float rectangle(float lenght, float breadth) { return lenght * breadth; }
```

Feel free to ask any additional questions

Comment: Thanks For This solution I appreciate your help. Can you please explain me what will "continue" statement  does in this code it will help me to understand this code better.

Comment: Can you please explain me what does that continue function does

Comment: @NikhilGaikwad: a [`continue` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/continue) causes the loop to go to the next iteration, effectively. In this case the loop restarts if the input is invalid, and otherwise hits the `break` statement, which causes the loop to end.